# CSS 'scale' is breaking the jQuery 'fadeIn'

Tags: jquery, css, transform, fadein

I have a full width, transparent overlay fading in over the content when you click the menu button. My issue is that I have added a CSS transform scale effect to zoom out the content (which also blurs) and the scale is breaking the overlay fade.

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
    if(!$('.menu').hasClass('active')){
        $('.menu').addClass('active');

        $('.overlay-bg').fadeIn();

        $('.content').addClass('zoom');
        $('.content').addClass('blur');
    }else{
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');

        $('.overlay-bg').fadeOut();

        $('.content').removeClass('zoom');
        $('.content').removeClass('blur');
    }
});
```

The relevant CSS is:

```
.content{
    background-color: #fff; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    transition: all 1s ease; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.zoom{
    transform: scale(0.8); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/forxs/NAZ7D/1/

It appears to work correctly in Safari, but not Chrome (It hasn't been set up for FF or IE yet)

To clarify, since adding the scale, the overlay no longer fades in, it just appears after the animation time ends...

Confusingly, the fadeOut works fine.

Comment: I think I'm seeing the correct animation, it just turns to be very slow.

Comment: By the way, your JS code simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/NAZ7D/4/

Answer (score 1):

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/NAZ7D/2/)

Change your jQuery to:

```
$('.menu').click(function () {
    if (!$('.menu').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.menu').addClass('active');


        setTimeout(function () {

            $('.content').addClass('zoom blur');

        }, 50);

        $('.overlay-bg').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('active');

        $('.overlay-bg').fadeOut();

        $('.content').removeClass('zoom blur');
    }
});
```

The crucial part here is wrapping the initial transition in a timeout- this seems to force Chrome to order the rendering correctly.

Comment: It seems to be a conflict between the browser rendering of the transition happening simultaneously with jQuery's incremental manipulation of the elements CSS properties (display/opacity). There are one or two things out there on it (http://www.levihackwith.com/css-transitions-cause-jquery-fadein-to-not-work/) but I havent found a resolute explanation